# Validate a Json response using PAW rest client

Tags: paw

Lets say i make a rest call to the server and it sends back this JSON response

```
{
  "pageTotal": 1,
  "total": 10,
}
```

Is there a way i can automatically validate in PAW that the values match or lets say the values are integers and not strings

Please let me know.

Comment: There is no way to validate responses yet. Our plan is to add predicates / assertions that would allow you to add rules on HTTP status code, JSON responses, etc. so you can see whether a response is valid at a glance. Also it would allow you to run tests quickly. That's on our roadmap, but no schedule yet...

Comment: thanks @MichaMazaheri, in the mean while i will also check if i can figure out any other mechanism till PAW provides it.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri - just a suggestion, if not on your roadmap. One could use http://json-schema.org/ to validate JSON responses. I used this approach in https://github.com/clafonta/Mockey and it worked well.

Comment: @clafonta great idea, yes. I have JSON schema + JSON-LD + Swagger in mind for a long time, there's definitively a need for more support of these.